# Get the amplitude of a computational basis in stim

Tags: stim

How can I get the amplitudes of a specific computational basis state in stim?

I have looked into the `stim.TableauSimulator` which has a method `state_vector()`. However, it cannot work when the space is too large. Is there any other method for the purpose or any workarounds to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a magnitude out of a stabilizer state is not too hard. All you need to do for that is postselect onto the state, one qubit at a time, counting how many times the postselection is random. If the postselection ever fails, the magnitude is 0. If it succeeds at forcing every single qubit to match the desired state, the magnitude is $2^{-\text{randoms}/2}$. In fact this general idea works for any kind of state: as long as you can postselect, and know how likely the postselection was to succeed, you can compute the magnitude by iterative postselection.

Getting the phase is trickier. First of all, you need to deal with the fact that stabilizer tableaus have no global phase whereas state vectors do. It's easy to accidentally be inconsistent about the global phase from one call to the next. What I do is to always pick the smallest computational basis state with nonzero amplitude as the phase reference. But then that means you have to postselect down to two states, the desired state and the reference state, without messing up their relative phase, which is just more complicated.

Anyways, here's working tested code that does it. This particular code is $O(n^3)$ complexity where $n$ is the number of qubits, because under the hood it keeps transposing the tableau for each postselection. It may be possible to do better.

```
def amplitude_of_state(
        sim: stim.TableauSimulator,
        desired_state: int,
) -> complex:
    n = sim.num_qubits
    
    # Determine the magnitude of the target state.
    copy = sim.copy()
    num_random = 0
    for q in range(n)[::-1]:
        desired_bit = bool(desired_state & (1 << q))
        z = copy.peek_z(q)
        is_random = z == 0
        forced_bit = z == -1
        if is_random:
            num_random += 1
        elif desired_bit != forced_bit:
            return 0
        copy.postselect_z(q, desired_value=desired_bit)
    magnitude = 2**-(num_random / 2)

    # For a phase reference, use the smallest state with non-zero amplitude.
    copy = sim.copy()
    ref_state = 0
    for q in range(n)[::-1]:
        z = copy.peek_z(q)
        forced_bit = z == -1
        ref_state |= forced_bit << q
        copy.postselect_z(q, desired_value=forced_bit)
    if ref_state == desired_state:
        return magnitude

    # Postselect away states that aren't the desired or reference states.
    # Also move the ref state to |00..00> and the desired state to |00..01>.
    copy = sim.copy()
    found_difference = False
    for q in range(n):
        desired_bit = bool(desired_state & (1 << q))
        ref_bit = bool(ref_state & (1 << q))
        if desired_bit == ref_bit:
            copy.postselect_z(q, desired_value=ref_bit)
            if desired_bit:
                copy.x(q)
        elif not found_difference:
            found_difference = True
            if q:
                copy.swap(0, q)
            if ref_bit:
                copy.x(0)
        else:
            # Remove difference between target state and ref state at this bit.
            copy.cnot(0, q)
            copy.postselect_z(q, desired_value=ref_bit)

    # The phase difference between |00..00> and |00..01> is what we want.
    # Since other states are gone, this is the bloch vector phase of qubit 0.
    assert found_difference
    s = str(copy.peek_bloch(0))
    if s == "+X":
        return +magnitude
    if s == "-X":
        return -magnitude
    if s == "+Y":
        return 1j*magnitude
    if s == "-Y":
        return -1j*magnitude

    raise NotImplementedError("Bug. State isolation failed.")
```